# In lambda func slice a str does not work as intended

Tags: pandas, lambda

I have the following code. The 1st block works as intended. The intended result is col4 will hold values from col 2 if the col3 value does not end with 7. Otherwise, col4 value will be col2 minus 1. But when I merge the line 2 with the 3 as the 2nd code block shows, it does not work. What is the problem?

```py
data=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4],'col2':[2018, 2018, 2019, 2020], 'col3':[2347, 1327, 2355, 2111]})
data['t']=data.col3.astype('str').str.slice(3)
data['col4']=data.apply(lambda x: x.col2-1 if x.t=='7' else x.col2, axis=1)
data
```

This does not work:

```
data=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4],'col2':[2018, 2018, 2019, 2020], 'col3':[2347, 1327, 2355, 2111]})
#data['t']=data.col3.astype('str').str.slice(3)
data['col4']=data.apply(lambda x: x.col2-1 if x.col3.astype('str').str.slice(3)=='7' else x.col2, axis=1)
data
```

Comment: what's the result and how it is different from the expected result. please share more details

Comment: Intended result is col4 will hold values from col 2 if the col3 value does not end with 7. Otherwise, col4 value will be col2 minus 1

Comment: can you please include that in the question? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```py
data=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4],'col2':[2018, 2018, 2019, 2020], 'col3':[2347, 1327, 2355, 2111]})
data['col4']=data.apply(lambda x: x['col2']-1 if x['col3'].astype('str')[3]=='7' else x['col2'], axis=1)
data

-----------------------------------------------
   col1  col2   col3    col4
0   1    2018   2347    2017
1   2    2018   1327    2017
2   3    2019   2355    2019
3   4    2020   2111    2020
-----------------------------------------------
```

The `apply` method iterates over all rows of a data frame and applies a function to it. For the first `x` row you would get:

```py
col1       1
col2    2018
col3    2347
```

If you then execute `x.col3.astype('str')`, you would get `'2347'`. Therefore, you can just slice it directly using `string_value[3]` instead of applying `.str.slice(3)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are absolutely correct, but why I could not use .str.slice(3)?

Comment: If you, for instance, look at the first row and select `col3` you get the following type: `type(data.loc[0].col3.astype(str))` -> `numpy.str_` . And the `.str` method is not supported for `numpy` objects. It's only supported for `pd.Series` objects.